# Access multi table query returns blanks for one table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have no programming or database background (other than as end user), and I'm building a database with Access in 365.  I have a very limited grasp of SQL.

I've written a multi-table query to base a report off of, and it mostly works.  It will return all the requested data for all but one table `(CostumeInventory)`.  For that table, it creates the columns `(ItemName, Description, Condition, RentalRate, ReplacementValue)`, but the rows are blank in those columns. [image: Screenshot].  In the CostumeInventory table they are required, set to short text, and all do contain data.

In query design if I R click the join to CostumeInventory, I have option 3 selected. [image: Screenshot2] 1 returns nothing, and 2 tells me to fix the "ambiguous outer join" error when I try to run it.  I tried creating sub-queries two different ways (one joining RentalInvenory and CostumeInventory, and the other joining all the Rental-- tables to CostumeInventory), and neither yielded any results.  Any suggestions I can try?  Thank you in advance!  Below is the code Access wrote:

```
SELECT RentalClients.CompanyName, RentalDetails.ShowTitle, RentalDetails.Designer,
    RentalDetails.OpeningDate, RentalDetails.ClosingDate, RentalDetails.FirstFitArrivalDate,
    RentalDetails.ApprovalDate, RentalDetails.ReturnDate, RentalClients.CostumeContact,
    RentalClients.CostumeEmail,
    RentalInventory.InventoryID, CostumeInventory.ItemName, CostumeInventory.Description,
    CostumeInventory.Condition, CostumeInventory.RentalRate, CostumeInventory.ReplacementValue
FROM (RentalClients
  INNER JOIN RentalDetails ON RentalClients.ClientID = RentalDetails.ClientID) 
  INNER JOIN (CostumeInventory
    RIGHT JOIN RentalInventory
    ON CostumeInventory.InventoryRecordID = RentalInventory.InventoryID)
  ON RentalDetails.RentalID = RentalInventory.RentalID
WHERE (((RentalDetails.RentalID)=[forms]![frmUpdateRental]![cboSelectRental]) AND
  ((RentalInventory.ReturnedApproval)=False) AND
  ((RentalInventory.ReturnedOpening)=False) AND
  ((RentalInventory.ReturnedFinal)=False));
```

Comment: Start with `RentalInventory` as the first table and left join the next one (option 2)

Comment: @Charlieface So would that read like this?:
INNER JOIN (Rental Inventory
LEFT JOIN CostumeInventory
ON RentalInventory.InventoryID = CostumeInventory.InventoryRecordID

Comment: No it should go `FROM RentalInventory LEFT JOIN CostumeInventory INNER JOIN RentalDetails ON ... INNER JOIN RentalClients ON ... ON...` i.e. the other tables should be between `LEFT JOIN CostumeInventory` and it's `ON`condition

Comment: Thanks, that did it!  I also had a dataype mis-match which I fixed (why trying a left join earlier did not work for me).  It's working great now, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

From what you have presented, this is what I think you have:

A RentalClient can have many RentalDetails. Join: ClientID

A RentalDetail uses multiple RentalInventory. Join: Rental ID

This is the part where there appears to be a discrepancy:

The RentalInventory table appears to be an associative table used to resolve a many-to-many relationship between an Inventory table with Primarykey(SetID, InventoryID) and the RentalDetails table with PrimaryKey(RentalID)

Since I don't see an Inventory table in your query, there are 2 possibilities:

1. You are missing an Inventory Table with PrimaryKey(SetID, InventoryID) and the table CostumeInventory is a dependent child of that table so that we get:

```
SELECT *
FROM RentalClients 
INNER JOIN RentalDetails ON RentalClients.ClientID = RentalDetails.ClientID
INNER JOIN RentalInventory ON RentalDetails.RentalID= RentalInventory.RentalID
INNER JOIN Inventory ON RentalInventory.SetID=Inventory.SetID 
and RentalInventory.InventoryID=Inventory.InventoryID
LEFT JOIN CostumeInventory on Inventory.SetID=CostumeInventory.SetID 
and Inventory.InventoryID=Inventory.InventoryID
```

2. The second possibility is that the CostumeInventory table **is** the Inventory table with an autogenerated InventoryRecordID and a unique constraint on InventoryID and SetID. If so, your join is incorrect and it shows that a mistake was made during modeling - The RentalInventory table should only have the fields RentalID and InventoryRecordID (to represent SetID and InventoryID). To fix this issue with your query (without touching the model), your query should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM RentalClients 
INNER JOIN RentalDetails ON RentalClients.ClientID = RentalDetails.ClientID
INNER JOIN RentalInventory ON RentalDetails.RentalID= RentalInventory.RentalID
LEFT JOIN CostumeInventory ON RentalInventory.SetID=CostumeInventory.SetID and RentalInventory.InventoryID=Inventory.InventoryID
```

InventoryRecordID is usually some autogenerated number in most systems so any join to it is probably incorrect. It should be on SetID and InventoryID as that fits more with the other side of the equation for the associative table RentalInventory, the first already handled by RentalID. Again, this assumes that option #2 reflects the true situation.

**If there is no unique constraint on the fields SetID and InventoryID in the CostumeInventory table, then #1 above is most likely the case.**

Overall, MS Access by behavior through the design view tends to add many brackets/parentheses to queries rendering the SQL complicated and a bit harder to read when you go to the SQL view. If you can, you should simplify for understanding - write it your own way (using aliases if needed) and replace it in SQL view and it should reflect in the design view.

Comment: Thanks!  It was situation #2.  I did have a datype mis-match that I missed earlier with my FK's and once that was corrected it's working.